# Increase Spark Executors on Zeppelin

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I'm setting up a cluster with Hortnworks (HDP 2.4). I have a 4 nodes cluster each having (16Gb-RAM, 8-CPUs). I also have Spark installed with Zeppelin Notebook in order to use python (pyspark).

My problem is: I started with a configuration of 3 nodes and later I added another new node (so totally 4 as said before), anyway the number of executors on Spark remains "3".

I see on the web that the number of executors is settable in `SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES`, but this param is present only in `spark-env template` of the config page of Spark in Ambari UI. Seems it demand to YARN the decision about executors, but in YARN I haven't found anything about this.

[image]

Definitively, How I can increase the number of executor in my Hortonworks Hadoop Cluster using Ambari?

Comment: Are you using spark with YARN cluster manager

Comment: I think yes...how can I check this configuration?

Comment: You can do it in 2 ways set "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled" to true or set number of executor instance "spark.executor.instances" to some number that you want

Comment: Where can I find these options? As said I see them only in "spark-env template" and this template says that these options are read in YARN Client mode.

Answer (score 9):

Pietro, you can change that on Zeppelin itself.

On the top right corner, open the menu, and enter the "Interpreter" configuration.

There is a section, called "interpreters". The last subsection is called "spark", and you should find this setting there.

If it is not, just insert it, editing the subsection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is the property for that? (I see only core max and memory)

Comment: Thomas Decaux, if you are using dynamic allocation you may select `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` as can be seen on the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). This would set the max number of executors. The initial number of executors is `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors` and the minimum is `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors`.
You also set `spark.executor.instances` (as an alternative to --num-executors), if you don't want to play with `spark.dynamicAllocation`.

Comment: Thanks you, I didnt notice we can add Spark property here!

Answer (score 5):

From top right corner, click down arrow -> click Interpreter -> find spark2 interpreter -> edit it -> add following two:

- spark.shuffle.service.enabled -> true
- spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled -> true